# How to style a Textpath letter with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I would like to style some letters of a textPath with its content added via jquery.

```
 <path fill="none" id="red"  d="M179.38 313.55A94.65 94.65 0 0 1 155 250a95 95 0 1 1 95 95 94.6 94.6 0 0 1-60.33-21.6"/>
 <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#red" class="text1 curve" startOffset="0%">              
      </textPath>
</text>`
```

jQuery:

```
var svgText1 = document.querySelector('.text1');
var arcus = $('button').data("content"); 
svgText1.textContent = arcus;
```

HTML:

```
<button data-content="some text">       
</button>
```

The question is how to style, for example, the word:** text**

I am able to change the data content of textPath but I can´t style it. I have tested using **Tspan**  or manipulating the CSS via jQuery without results.

https://codepen.io/charlyta/pen/gOjWaPY

Comment: If your problem is solved, excellent, but please don’t add “solved” to the title, instead wait until you can accept an appropriate answers if you wish to accept your own answer that’s absolutely fine, but you do have to wait a couple of days. Accepting an answer lets the system know it’s been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. Just changing textcontent by innerHTML

example working here: https://codepen.io/charlyta/pen/gOjWaPY

```
   <button class="Button" data-content=" You are
        <tspan font-weight='bold' fill='red' >not</tspan>
      a banana."> CHANGE TEXT</button>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- to hide the path, it is usually wrapped in a <defs> element -->
  <!-- <defs> -->
  <path
    id="MyPath"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50" />
  <!-- </defs> -->

  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath" class="text">Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

jquery

```
var myText = $('.Button').data("content"); 
var Text = document.querySelector('.text');

$( ".Button" ).click(function() {
Text.innerHTML = myText;
});
```